# How to empty a cell on Sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I'm using python and sqlite3 to manage a small database, I would like that at the end of the project only a few boxes were emptied.

Here's what I tried to do but it gives me error:

```
cloc.execute("DELETE FROM {}(locpar) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,), (item,))
cloc.execute("DELETE FROM {}(stoppar) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,), (item,))
cloc.execute("DELETE FROM {}(locdes) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,), (item,))
cloc.execute("DELETE FROM {}(stopdes) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,), (item,))
```

Output:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "(": syntax error
```

Here is what the database transformation should be
[image: Before]

[image: What should be after]

Comment: use `print( "DELETE FROM {}(locpar) WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,) )` to see if you created correct SQL query. It seems you have mistake.

Comment: It seems you have to learn SQL. To delete values in cell you have to use `UPDATE` and replace values with empty strings. `DELETE` is used to remove full row, not to remove values in cells.

Comment: I've already tried it lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to learn SQL.

`DELETE` is used only to remove full row, not values in cells.

You have to use `UPDATE` and put new values in cells - ie. `NULL` or empty string

```
cloc.execute("UPDATE {} SET locpar=NULL, stoppar=NULL, locdes=NULL, stopdes=NULL WHERE chat_id = (?);".format(item4,), (item,))
```

Comment: sorry I made typo - it has to be `UPDATE` instead of `UDPATE`